# Safe Upgrade of nVidia Driver on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, drivers, graphics-card, upgrade

The documentation from nVidia is on installing for a first time. I followed [these instructions](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-10.0-download-archive?target_os=Linux&target_arch=x86_64&target_distro=Ubuntu&target_version=1804&target_type=deblocal) for the first time install on a fresh Ubuntu 18.04 server. The server has nvidia-docker installed and thus the actual server is free from unneeded packages.

The update to PyTorch 1.7 (from 1.5) requires new drivers. I understand that I can type:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

HOWEVER, since I am 300 miles away from the server, I cannot risk bricking it. My experience with nVidia drivers is: minor tinkering equals days of suffering. Therefore, what is the standard way (or method that's worked many times) to *upgrade* nVidia drivers?

Specifically, I need to upgrade from **410.48** to **455.32** which I think comes with [CUDA 11.1.1](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads?target_os=Linux&target_arch=x86_64&target_distro=Ubuntu&target_version=1804&target_type=deblocal)

(Please: before down-voting, provide a clear step-by-step link to documentation that shows a safe driver upgrade method that explains why it is safe. I frankly have not found one yet. If I already provided the answer, please pile on the confirmations. Closed CROSSPOST from SO.)

Comment: I should note that most apt methods I read have many people suffering from side-effects that render the gpu useless. I too had trouble with apt updates and had to nuke the server last year for a fresh install.

Comment: NVIDIA won't be providing official upgrade guide for the apt package because it's not maintained by them. You already have it installed, so you're on package maintainer's mercy now. In theory this package should safely upgrade by itself. In practice, as you've noticed, it's not always so simple. Just prepare for the suffering.

Comment: So I used there local deb package install method from nVidia (linked above). Do you have experience with that? The maintainer should still be nVidia or am I mistaken? The masochist in me quiets down whenever nVidia is mentioned.. hence the post.